# How to implement a get(int index) method for an ordered array list

Tags: java

The method should return the item at the given index.  Throws an exception if the index is invalid. If there is an item in the given index then it should also return the index of the found item, if not then it should return -1 if the item is not in the array.

This is what i have done so far:

```
public T get(int index){
      int num=-1;
      if(index<0 || index>numItems){
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Index is out of bounds: "    + index);
      }
      else
        return sortedArray[index];
}
```

Comment: You've posted requirements and code, but no question -- what is your specific question? What's wrong with your code? Is it compiling? Not running? Misbehaving?

Comment: This doesn't look right: `return index;` Wouldn't you return the item corresponding to this index instead? `sortedArray[index]`?

Comment: Nothing after `return sortedArray[index];` will ever execute.

Comment: Sorry about that. It fails to compile. I get an error: Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to T@HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Because you said `return index;` and index is an int. Same for `num`.

Comment: The *return index;* will have no chance to be execute...

Comment: @RRTW True, but it will still cause compilation errors being in there.

Comment: So how would i return the index number in this case? @Gavin

Comment: How about *return new T(index);* ?

Comment: The "instructions" contradict each other. First it says " should return the **item** at the given index" then it says "Returns **index** of the found item". Contradicting requirements are impossible to implement. You should get clarification from whomever gave you those requirements.

Comment: How is this code `if(sortedArray[index]!=null){` even reachable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding a basic rule of functions. They can only return one thing. It looks like you are trying to return `T` and an `int`. This is not possible the way you are attempting. Your requirements don't make much sense either. It sounds like you are getting an index, and you just return the item at the index (which can easily be done with the `[ ]` operator), but then you say you are to return the index of the found item? The found item is at the index you pass to the function..

Comment: The requirement is that the method should return the item at a given index. If there is an item in that index, it should also return the index number. If not, then it should return -1.@Gavin

Comment: Why would you return the index of the item if you're already given the index?

Comment: *the method should return the item*  , so there is no way to let your method *also return the index number*.   And, the index was given by someone who called your method, he already know the index, why should you return it again ?

Comment: Oh okay its making more sense now. What about returning -1 if the item is not in the array? @Gavin

Comment: @RRTW, yeah i understand what you are saying. Thank you.

Comment: @FredPeter How could the item not be at the index? Either it's there or you're out of bounds.

Comment: @Gavin, oh yeah that is true. Sorry, the instructions i received completely confused me since i am new to Java. I will ask for the instructions to get rectified.